# No me sale calcular la suma de los números naturales desde 1 hasta n

Tags: javascript, html

Deberá desarrollar un programa que calcule la suma de los números naturales desde 1 hasta n (n debe ingresarse por teclado). Debe resolver el ejercicio utilizando Do While.

```html
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Document</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <script> 
            var suma, cont; 
            suma = 0; 
            cont = 1; 
            do{ suma = suma + 1; }while{ cont < 5 ; } 
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script> 
  var suma, cont;

  suma = 0;
  cont = 1;
do{
  suma = suma + 1;
}while{
  cont < 5 ;
}
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Hola! El código va EN la pregunta (te ayudo a acomodarlo). Puedes [edit] todas las veces que necesites para añadir información... ahora bien, qué error sale en la consola de tu navegador? Revísalo y edita tu pregunta para añadir esa información

Comment: De paso, revisa la [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while) del do-while para JavaScript

Comment: Java y JavaScript no son para nada lo mismo... lo que estás usando es JavaScript, no JAVA. Por más que los nombres se parezcan, no tienen nada que ver! Por favor usa las etiquetas correctas

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis del do... while es la siguiente:

```
do {
   <sentencia1>
   <sentencia2>
   ...
} while (<condición>);
```

Entonces podemos ver que estás usando {} cuando la condición a evaular debe ir entre ()

Por otro lado, la condición que evalúas

```
cont < 5
```

Es de prueba me imagino, pero no cumple con el enunciado, que indica que permita sumar hasta el número n (ingresado por teclado).

Deberá ser, si queremos que incluya hasta n, menor o igual a ese n.

```
cont <= n
```

Por otro lado, para pedir ingresar un valor al usuario, una de las formas más sencillas es utilizar

```
<variable-a-recibir-el-dato> = window.prompt(<mensaje-al-usuario>);
```

De ese modo podrías hacer algo así

```
let n = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");
```

Por último, en suma debes almacener la suma, y en cont, incrementar de a 1 los valores de los números, entonces debes considerar las siguientes sentencias

```
suma = suma + 1;
```

y reemplazarlas por:

```
suma = suma + cont; // sumaría primero 0+1=1, luego 1+2=3, luego 2+3=5, etc. 
cont = cont + 1; // primero será 1, luego 2, 3, ...
```

## Código propuesto

```html
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
        <title>Document</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <script> 
            var suma, cont;
            let n = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");
            suma = 0; 
            cont = 1;
            do {
              console.log(cont);
              suma = suma + cont;
              cont = cont + 1;
            } while(cont <= n); 
            console.log(suma)
        </script> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Puede variar, depende la interpretación de la consigna y lo que puedan utilizar, pero fue bueno mostrar lo que intentaste. Espero haber sido claro.